# If an object is unhashable it's an error to ask if it's a dictionary key

Tags: python, dictionary

If an object is unhashable, like a set, it is an error to ask whether it's a key of a dictionary:

```
>>> key = set()
>>> key in {}
Traceback (most recent call last):
TypeError: unhashable type: 'set'
```

I'm just wondering why this is.

edit: I understand that the object needs to be hashed, but not why it needs to be an error if it can't.

Comment: You can make a set hashable of you make your own type and implement ``__hash__`` and other comparison methods needed.

Answer (score 2):

That's because the first thing Python needs to do in order to check whether it's in the dict is to attempt to hash the object.

As an alternate design decision, Python could potentially have handled this case; it would be done in `dict.__contains__` implementation, catching the `TypeError` and returning `False`.  But this provides less information to the user than just leaving the exception unhandled, and is therefore arguably *less* useful.

Answer (score 1):

That's because checking for dictionary membership requires that the object be **hashed** first and then compared using `__eq__`.

Consider the following toy example:

```
class Key(object):
  def __hash__(self):
    print('calling hash')
    return 1

  def __eq__(self, other):
    print('calling eq')
    return True

dct = {1: 2}
Key() in dct
# calling hash
# calling eq
```

In your example, the `set()` does not get past the hash stage, and an error is correctly raised, rather than passed silently.

Comment: I understand it needs to be hashed to be found. I'm just not sure why it's an error.

Comment: @PeterWood I'm not sure why you would expect it wouldn't be an error, if `hash(set())` is.

Comment: I see. Any operation with `dict` where you pass a key will produce an error if the object isn't hashable. It's consistent.

Answer (score 0):

Making a set be a key in a dictionary is iffy because set is a mutable data structure.

What happens when you add some things to the set? Should 'a' continue to be treated as a key in the dict or should some other set with the original value of a be treated as a key instead?

To use a set-like structure as a key, use an immutable 'frozenset' instead. You cannot change the value of a frozenset after instantiating it and so python can safely allow it to be a key in a dict.

Comment: I don't want to use a set as a key, I'm just wondering why it's an error to check whether an unhashable object is a key to a dictionary.

Comment: Because dictionaries need keys to be hashable. It is part of how dictionaries work! ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table )

Comment: I know. But if an object isn't a key to a dictionary, why is it an error to check whether it is?

Comment: Because the method to check membership involves hashing the the object. You might prefer python to automatically return False for unhashable objects but most people won't like that since it might hide bugs related to people trying to use unhashable keys on dicts without realizing that nothing is actually getting stored in the dict.

Answer (score 0):

It's more useful that way.

---

`key in d` is supposed to be equivalent to

```
any(key == k for k in d)
```

which can actually be True for unhashable objects:

```
d = {frozenset(): 1}
key = set()
print(any(key == k for k in d)) # prints True
```

So trying to always return `False` for unhashable objects would create an inconsistency. In theory, we could try to fall back to that `for` loop, but that would lead to silent O(len(d)) performance degradation and defeat the benefits of a dict for little gain.

Also, even if `key in d` was always `False` for an unhashable `key`, or if it had some kind of fallback, most instances where such a test even happens would still probably be due to bugs rather than deliberate. An exception is more useful than a `False` result.

Comment: I don't agree on the "equivalent".  `nan` for example breaks that.  And it's glossing over the most important detail: the expectation is that `in` will be like O(1) and anything using `for k in d` will be O(n).

Comment: This is a useful thought. It probably would be due to bugs.

Comment: @wim: NaN breaks that, sure, but it also violates the unchecked precondition for dict keys that `==` is an equivalence relation. Dicts aren't expected to behave reasonably in the presence of keys like that. If you're using NaN as a dict key, you're doing something wrong already.

Comment: I'm not proposing to implement `in` for dicts with a `for` loop (and nobody else's answer says anything about O(1) or O(N) either), but the semantics (though not the runtime) are supposed to be equivalent.